# MSIE Speech Recognition ActiveX

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I'm writing some code on MSIE+SAPI technology, and I wanted to **experiment** with speech recognition.

I've been able to use **text to speech** as follows:

```
var KC_TTS = new ActiveXObject("Sapi.SpVoice");
// ...
KC_TTS.Speak("Hello, world!", 1);
```

So, by convention, there must be some speech recognition ActiveX that can be loaded and used similarly. However, I can't seem to be able to find the name of this ActiveX, and as such, I can't find any associated documentation as well.

**My questions**

What is the name of the MS ActiveX that allows speech recognition?

Where can I find some documentation on its use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the name of the MS ActiveX that allows speech recognition?

You can use SAPI.SpInprocRecognizer  or SAPI.SpSharedRecognizer

> Where can I find some documentation on its use?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms722071(v=VS.85).aspx

See example here

http://julius.sourceforge.jp/sapi/Samples/JavaScript/dictcommand.html

Comment: Some great pointers! Though I don't understand the demo much :(

Comment: I'm stuck in the part about `Ctxt::Recognition()`. Is it correct JS syntax even?

Comment: Hello Christian. Ctxt::Recognition is not Javascript syntax, it's JScript (Microsoft version) convention to define event handler for SAPI.  See for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720907(v=VS.85).aspx